# How many base cases can we have for a recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, random

I have a method `rand2()` that `returns 0 or 1` randomly.

I am trying to create a method 
`rand3()` which will use `rand2()` and `return 0,1,2` 
with an equal probability.

I came up with a recursive solution that considers 4 combinations of 0,1.

All in all I wrote this function, with more than 1 base case, in a hope that it will work.

But it seems like recusive functions can't have more than one base case.

Here is my Code:

```
public static int rand3(){
        String str = "";
        str+= rand2();
        str+= rand2();
        System.out.println(str);

        if(str=="00")
            return 0;
        else if(str=="11")
            return 1;
        else if( str=="01")
            return 2;          
        else
            return rand3();
    }
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it seems like recusive functions can't have more than one base case.

That is not correct.  A recursive function can have as many base-cases as you need.  (And some recursive functions definitely need more than one; e.g. a recursive fibonacci function.)

> All in all I wrote this function, with more than 1 base case, in a hope that it will work.

What makes you think that it doesn't work?

---

With a little bit of thought you could refactor that code so that there is only one base-case.

Hint: rand2() returns an INTEGER ... and you can perform ADDITION and MULTIPLICATION on integers

Comment: `rand2() + rand2(); ` this equation gives 1 0 2 1 not unique .  But 2*rand2() + rand2(); this one gives 0 1 2 3 unique and suitable  and base case will be  `if (randSum<3) return randSum;`  It worked; Is it what you thought about?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I was hinting at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you need recursion (unless it is an academic exercise of course). Just wrap the `if` block within a loop and break out of the loop in any of the first three alternatives, leaving the 4th one to re-run through the loop.

Note that you will also need to include within the loop the assignments for `str`.